# Core Data server syncing

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a dilemma regarding Core Data and syncing data with server. 
I wrote an app which uses Core Data, don't use id attributes, everything is set with relationships. Most of data is being generated on device and should be sent to server as backup. On the other hand, there is some data that can be reused among users and I want to have control over it, i.e. modifying, deleting, adding.

**Question**
When sending data to server, what's prefered way of dealing with relationships? In my opinion, it would be very inefficient to think in terms of Core Data, sending all relation objects to server and then deal with them if they already exist on server. So, using uniqueId is obligatory? Generating ones on server which will be shared and others on devices? Is there any other approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you do need a connection between the objects. When on device this is handled by pointers which have a bit more then the functionality of an ID. But when communicating with another device such as server you will need a bit more. In most cases this link is generated with IDs as it seems the easiest way of doing this. How would you expect to do such a link? And why is this approach bugging you?

Comment: Using Core Data is nice because you don't have to maintain ids and think of your model as of DB. But it seems that I have to think of it as DB as well. No big deal, just thought there was some new cool way of dealing with it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the server database works with foreign keys, one common solution is to introduce id attributes and set them to some invalid state for new objects. For example, for new relationships you could generate an arbitrary number of unique "invalid" ids by using negative integers. The server would have to then assign new (server-unique) ids and send them back to the client. Of course, when importing data from the server, you replace foreign keys with relationships.

So if you have potentially more than one device trying to modify data also used by other users or devices, the server will have to be part of the solution. Otherwise, you could just generate unique IDs so the server can store the relationships.

Comment: You are right. My fingers were a lot quicker than my brain. Of course the server will create IDs and send it back to device.
I just wish I didn't have ID attributes in my entites... I don't need foreign keys in Core Data, which is nice, just as you said.